# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'order clause'

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make pagination after sorting in my Laravel project , so I did this method, it sorts my data but when I want to see next paginate table it shows me this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'order clause'
SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY `` DESC limit 3 OFFSET 3
```

**My method**

```
 public function Sortfilter(Request $request)
    {
        $active = Customer::where('active','=','1')->count();
        $inactive = Customer::where('active','=','0')->count();
        $customer = Customer::query();

        $customer = Customer::orderBy($request->filter,'desc')->paginate(3);
        return view('customers.index', compact('customer','inactive','active'));


    }
```

is there a method to save the $request->filter data when I click on next button

**EDIT**

when i sort my data the URL change like that : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sortCustomer?filter=phone&_token=9xw0q9MKa5ABZc4CwkLaPqf5ko4BhJ4ZaEk0VKYY`

and when i click to the pagination button the URL be like that :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sortCustomer?page=2
```

Comment: probably `$request->filter` doesn't have value at some point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Laravel there is the option to [append query string values to pagination links](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values).

Using this your code could look like this:

```
public function Sortfilter(Request $request)
{
    $active = Customer::where('active','=','1')->count();
    $inactive = Customer::where('active','=','0')->count();
    $customer = Customer::query();

    $customer = Customer::orderBy($request->filter,'desc')->paginate(3)->withQueryString();
    return view('customers.index', compact('customer','inactive','active'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is sometimes your `$request->filter` is empty, so adding a default value when it's empty fixes that.

```
public function Sortfilter(Request $request)
{
    $active = Customer::where('active','=','1')->count();
    $inactive = Customer::where('active','=','0')->count();
    $customer = Customer::query();
    $filter = $request->filter ?: 'created_at';

    $customer = Customer::orderBy($filter,'desc')->paginate(3)>appends(['filter' =>  $request->filter]);
    return view('customers.index', compact('customer','inactive','active'));
}
```

Comment: how can i save the data of filter to reused again when i click in next pagination button ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing **'' (null)** in the first parameter of orderBy clause.

please confirm that the value in the **$request->filter** parameter not null and it should be a column name as in the customer table.

Comment: for the first time when i sort my table is not null , but when i want to see the next page of my table by clicking to next pagination button , it take the $filter as `null`

Comment: yes , that will happen. please follow the Lucky Person's answer that is good solution. make default coloum when ther filter parameter is null.